# making a loop show as a counter in csh

Tags: loops, counter, csh

Im currently working on a code in csh and when it gets to the loop for example it goes

```
loop end count=1
loop end count=2
loop end count=3
loop end count=4
loop end count=5 etc etc
```

Is there a way I can make it just say

```
loop end count=(number just counts up here without adding lines)
```

so I don't keep getting a wall of text when I run the code? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are on a vt100 compatible terminal (most all linux terminals) you can generate appropriate terminal control codes:

```
 echo -n "count is:"
 echo -n "^[7" # save cursor position
 set i = 0
 while ( 1 )
  @ i = $i + 1
  echo -n "^[[u^[[K"  #move back to saved position and erase end of line
  echo -n "i=" , $i
  sleep 1
 end
```

Note "^[" is the ASCII escape character, *not* caret-bracket. How you get that
in a script will depend on your editor.